# How to set a property of a prototype object for a single class

Tags: javascript, prototype

Say I change the object prototype like so:

```
Object.prototype.test = {val: 5, abc: 8};
```

Then I change a property of `test` for `Array`:

```
Array.prototype.test.abc = 20;
```

Then if I print the base `test` variable:

```
console.log(Object.prototype.test); // {val: 5, abc: 20}
console.log(({}).test);        // {val: 5, abc: 20}
console.log(([]).test);       // {val: 5, abc: 20}
```

How do I still have arrays inherit `val` as 5, but have an `abc` value of 20 without affecting `Object`'s prototype

Comment: You have a single object set as the `test` property; if you want different objects you'd need to clone and modify.

Comment: Nota Bene: you should never *ever* actually do this. Ever. Don't modify prototypes you don't own.

Comment: @JaredSmith A lot of libraries do it, but yes. I read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) which doesn't give a reason not to

Comment: @FireCubez No library modifies `Array.prototype` or `Object.prototype` :-)

Comment: At least not much since the aptly named `prototype.js`. What libraries do occasionally do is conditionally add standard features that are missing in the current environment. Polyfilling standardized properties is different than adding random stuff because reasons.

Comment: @FireCubez Read more. Specifically https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes. Which pretty much states flat out you shouldn't do this, and explains why. I would call that a "reason not to".

Comment: ~~@DaveNewton I read it. It just says "dont do it" without giving a reason~~ Nevermind, it breaks encapsulation

Comment: @FireCubez ... What is "This technique is called monkey patching and breaks encapsulation." if not a reason?! It gives an example of the "only good reason" (back-porting now-standard functionality), meaning reasons that are *not* that are not good reasons, so any other reason you can think of almost certainly falls under the "not a good reason" category. I don't think it could be any clearer, really, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `Array.protoype` does not have its own `test` property. So when you try to access it with `Array.prototype.test.abc = 20;` it looks up the prototype chain and find the `.test` object on `Object.prototype` and sets *its* `.abc` value to 20.

You can give `Array.prototype` it's own property `test` with something like:

```js
Object.prototype.test = {val: 5, abc: 8};

Array.prototype.test = Object.assign({}, Object.prototype.test)
Array.prototype.test.abc = 20;

console.log(({}).test.abc);       // 8
console.log(([]).test.abc);       // 20
```

You could also link the `test` object from Array to Object so properties not found on `Array.prototype.test` will defer up the chain to `Object.prototype.test`, although this starts to get confusing:

```js
Object.prototype.test = {val: 5, abc: 8};

Array.prototype.test = Object.create(Object.prototype.test)
Array.prototype.test.abc = 20;

console.log(([]).test.abc);      // shadows with it's own abc
Object.prototype.test.abc = 500  // changes in object have no effect
console.log(([]).test.abc);      // still 20

console.log(([]).test.val);      // no val on Array's test so it defers to object prototype
Object.prototype.test.val = 100  // changing object changes array
console.log(([]).test.val);
```

…not that I really recommend any of this beyond test and exploring the ecosystem.

Comment: Instead of `Array.prototype.test = Object.create(Object.prototype.test)` I could do `Array.prototype.test = Object.create(Array.prototype.__proto__.test)` right? More generally I can just do `ABC.prototype.test = Object.create(ABC.prototype.__proto__.test)`?

Comment: Sure @FireCubez since `Array.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype`